# Read property file value truncating in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone please help to read property file value, I am using below code to get but it's truncating the '=' values.

```
keyVal=`cat configReplace.properties | grep "$key" | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

by using above for below entry getting the value till resource only

```
key1=https://mytest.web.net/sampleuri/api?resource=respVal?resource2=respVal2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut -d'=' -f2` splits on *all* equals signs and gives you only the second column. Use `-f2-` to get the second onwards.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding back it's working til first '=' second respval2 not getting. Can you please help how to get all equal values except key

Comment: @Sreenivas It's working fine for me. Please provide a [mre] in the question. For example here's what I tried: `echo 'k=url?a=1?b=2' | cut -d'=' -f2` -> `url?a`, `cut -d'=' -f2-` -> `url?a=1?b=2`

Comment: Yeah it's working now as expected thanks alot. it's problem with my property only. now all fine.. thanks alot... :)

Comment: @Sreenivas I see your answer and I fixed it for you. But why did you post your own answer? Is there anything unclear about mine? And you don't need to post the exact code that solves the problem.

Comment: your answer is absolutely right and helps me.. i posted for my future purpose to remember.. i have deleted my as you suggested no need to post...